# Recognizing patterns given a set of sentences

Tags: regex, string, data-structures, pattern-matching

I have a text file with lots of sentences. These sentences can occur in patterns. How do I recognize these patterns?

For example:

---

### i woke up in the morning

### i went to school

### i played football

### i came back home

### i woke up in the morning

### i went to school

### i played basketball

At this point I want the program to say that "I played football" should have appeared.

Comment: Use existing services that search school work for duplicates... If you want answer here - please show what you tried add more concrete definition of each of your "sentences", "patterns", "recognize" and "lots" words.

Comment: Show us what you've already tried?

Comment: I ve tried to implement it for a set of integers. Like repeating patterns. Suffix trees.

Comment: Can u post the text file u have and the pattern you want to match.

Comment: "Patterns"... Sentences that start with a consonant? Sentences of six words long? Sentences containing the word "patterns"? Sentences ending with a period? Sentences containing "u" where "you" was meant? Except for the last one, your post contains 2 out of 3 for all of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task seems to little bit complicate,but you can try this simple code for understanding or if finds it useful you can further implement it::

```
     //the sentences/input input String
    String sampleString1="xyz";
    String[] sampleString2=sampleString1.split(".");
    for(int i=1;i<=sampleString2.length;i++){
        //The pattern which you can specify to match with the sentence
        if(sampleString2[i].substring(0, 14).equals(sampleString2[0].substring(0,16))){
            //code to execute the matched sentence.
            System.out.println("Sentence matching with pattern ::" + sampleString2[i]);
        }
    }
```

If the pattern to be matched is the first line of the sequence ,then try this code.

Comment: I do not want to specify the pattern which I want to match. The program should intelligently find out that what must have occurred.

Comment: How this can be possible,there should be some sort of pattern to match,from a couple of sentences if you want to choose 1 sentence ,there should be some criteria which is to be set to qualify a selected sentence!

Comment: Assume that whatever occurs first is correct sequence. Since this is a small example I gave, u mighht have some confusion but the text files I have to deal with contain lots of repeating patterns.

Comment: check the above code ,i have edited it again as per your query.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote something similar, now I have to scale it up. :)